# DB2 If statement not working within XMLTABLE

Tags: xml, db2

I have the below sql, which takes a passed in xml, and generates another xml.

For  element firstName and lastName, if the attribute "encrypted" is true, I then call a function to decrypt the value.

But somehow, the sql always executes the line that calls the decrypt function - RDS.PCMS_DECRYPTION, regardless whether attribute "encrypted" is true or not.

is there something wrong with my sql?

Thanks

```
with origxml(xdoc) AS (VALUES XMLPARSE( DOCUMENT
    '
    <transactionSale>
        <TxnHeader action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnHeaderData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <encryptionID>DJ_KEY_2016</encryptionID>
      <externalAccount>R01843390</externalAccount>
      <finishDateTime>2016-04-27 14:20:21.42</finishDateTime>
      <legalTender>AUD</legalTender>
      <loyaltyValue>0.00</loyaltyValue>
      <operatorOperatorCode>52286</operatorOperatorCode>
      <processingTypeValidationCodeConst>58015</processingTypeValidationCodeConst>
      <sellingStore>2116</sellingStore>
      <sourceSystem>GIFTRGSTRY</sourceSystem>
      <startDateTime>2016-04-27 14:19:45.41</startDateTime>
      <status>0</status>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <tillStatus>0</tillStatus>
      <tradingDate>2012-07-30</tradingDate>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <transactionTypeTransactionType>3</transactionTypeTransactionType>
      <valueDue>183.00</valueDue>
      <valueGross>183.00</valueGross>
      <valueNett>166.36</valueNett>
      <valueRounding>0.00</valueRounding>
      <valueTax>16.64</valueTax>
    </TxnHeader>
    <TransactionQueue action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TransactionQueueData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <status>N</status>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
    </TransactionQueue>
    <TxnDetail action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <colour>N/A</colour>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>0</detailNumber>
      <externalStockNumber>4947149</externalStockNumber>
      <extRefNo>1234</extRefNo>
      <fulfilInfo>DELIVER</fulfilInfo>
      <level>0</level>
      <level5CompanyCode>DJ01</level5CompanyCode>
      <level5Level5ID>2743-157</level5Level5ID>
      <level5ProductGroupType>999003</level5ProductGroupType>
      <level5StructureType>1</level5StructureType>
      <operatorOperatorCode>52286</operatorOperatorCode>
      <pluNumber>0027131612278</pluNumber>
      <priceDiscountable>168.00</priceDiscountable>
      <priceSold>168.00</priceSold>
      <quantitySold>1.0</quantitySold>
      <saleDate>2016-04-27 14:20:09.41</saleDate>
      <sellingCompany>DJ01</sellingCompany>
      <sellingDepartmentCode>2743</sellingDepartmentCode>
      <sellingStore>2116</sellingStore>
      <sizeIndicator>50ML</sizeIndicator>
      <skuCode>2743-65773</skuCode>
      <skuOwner>DJ01</skuOwner>
      <skuOwnerType>1</skuOwnerType>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <systemPrice>168.00</systemPrice>
      <taxInclusive>1</taxInclusive>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <transLineTypeTransLineType>6</transLineTypeTransLineType>
      <unitOfMeasure>each</unitOfMeasure>
      <valueLine>168.00</valueLine>
      <valueLineAllDiscounts>168.00</valueLineAllDiscounts>
    </TxnDetail>
    <TxnCustomer action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnCustomerData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <customerStatus>1</customerStatus>
      <customerSubType>0</customerSubType>
      <customerType>1</customerType>
      <firstName encrypted="false">dAUbRNd7BlJNSLLMh7HHDLckpbDXYcm1Lbv9z8r+pVzXGBoQJhuJ9FmraHk534U1zwYk6ENm7P9Z24DzJZHdSEfuxca1v4c/tBQ79XHZWfBQKrYZDqX7WuVvkWm8sxdb4GQ1p4AchZZHR0xWS37xn4hSUgvjas5VuO/jFX3hNCYj+nw67kKqEWzO4Pkr8/iRBc2pGEgCr/ZzhAgafUuTyH1t2pQSn0JIYuulbacaHx3Q9P5WO+r3cb0hpaeHjB1ICKa+c9XLQ1KvqghJLJtTtQQWX1ixbnnbzw+Gnl0GUDitx7cxSF36RlCdIr226TrzGyilWiPi6NW+BH+zlgEp4A==</firstName>
      <gender>79303</gender>
      <lastName encrypted="true">bttvQ/R1pFKl1ILxUeymmFfLRJ6cnWOZQSjNch62S54p2LNczkAJO/xC+kK77TtVff7eh9hI2h4CRm00brhIa9/8yt4Crq+tYaY+VosFp7dCuHL+fYRTrzmWp0DI5tVYtYeIcg5VMbmuvSmpvmDz2zzdmB7GW7Rbh1dooD0oOeBDowPqu3fShCm2HKzFRDLTYnkdRJPne3bzL9BrRWwEeCWyoaca8NHozjsWz3Wfi5hJgwvs+DO4dm5wh4qMr+frAiO2EeszBCvptPzf6z45+MtgOckbgo1izJXwxjBwDN0ddvtnnbuxp+P3ojgVrF2bkj+AH55iE4q77oV181t9WQ==</lastName>
      <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <title>Mr</title>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <comment>Happy birthday</comment>
    </TxnCustomer>
    <TxnDetailCustomer action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailCustomerData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>0</detailNumber>
      <quantity>1.0</quantity>
      <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
    </TxnDetailCustomer>
    <TxnAddress action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnAddressData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <addressSequenceNumber>1</addressSequenceNumber>
      <addressSubTypeAddressSubType>3</addressSubTypeAddressSubType>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <customerSequenceNumber>1</customerSequenceNumber>
      <monthsAtAddress>-32768</monthsAtAddress>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <telephoneNumber>0452541141</telephoneNumber>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
    </TxnAddress>
    <TxnDetailAddress action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailAddressData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>0</detailNumber>
      <quantity>1.0</quantity>
      <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
    </TxnDetailAddress>
    <TxnDetailTaxes action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailTaxesData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <amount>15.27</amount>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>0</detailNumber>
      <flatAmountIncTax>0.00</flatAmountIncTax>
      <rate>10.0</rate>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <taxAuthorityCode>AU</taxAuthorityCode>
      <taxDate>2016-04-27 14:20:21.69</taxDate>
      <taxNumber>0</taxNumber>
      <taxRuleCode>GSTNONZERO</taxRuleCode>
      <taxRuleName>GST</taxRuleName>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <valueTaxable>168.00</valueTaxable>
    </TxnDetailTaxes>
    <TxnDetail action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>1</detailNumber>
      <fulfilInfo>DELIVER</fulfilInfo>
      <level>0</level>
      <level5ProductGroupType>0</level5ProductGroupType>
      <level5StructureType>0</level5StructureType>
      <operatorOperatorCode>52286</operatorOperatorCode>
      <priceDiscountable>15.00</priceDiscountable>
      <priceSold>15.00</priceSold>
      <quantitySold>1.0</quantitySold>
      <saleDate>2016-04-27 14:20:14.18</saleDate>
      <sellingCompany>DJ01</sellingCompany>
      <sellingDepartmentCode>601943</sellingDepartmentCode>
      <sellingStore>2116</sellingStore>
      <skuCode>601943-1</skuCode>
      <skuOwner>DJ01</skuOwner>
      <skuOwnerType>1</skuOwnerType>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <systemPrice>0.00</systemPrice>
      <taxInclusive>1</taxInclusive>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <transLineTypeTransLineType>22</transLineTypeTransLineType>
      <unitOfMeasure>each</unitOfMeasure>
      <valueLine>15.00</valueLine>
      <valueLineAllDiscounts>15.00</valueLineAllDiscounts>
    </TxnDetail>
    <TxnDetailTaxes action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnDetailTaxesData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <amount>1.36</amount>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>1</detailNumber>
      <flatAmountIncTax>0.00</flatAmountIncTax>
      <rate>10.0</rate>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <taxAuthorityCode>AU</taxAuthorityCode>
      <taxDate>2016-04-27 14:20:21.69</taxDate>
      <taxNumber>0</taxNumber>
      <taxRuleCode>GSTNONZERO</taxRuleCode>
      <taxRuleName>GST</taxRuleName>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <valueTaxable>15.00</valueTaxable>
    </TxnDetailTaxes>
    <TxnTaxes action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnTaxesData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <amount>16.64</amount>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>1</detailNumber>
      <rate>10.0</rate>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <taxAuthorityCode>AU</taxAuthorityCode>
      <taxDate>2016-04-27 14:20:21.69</taxDate>
      <taxRuleCode>GSTNONZERO</taxRuleCode>
      <taxRuleName>GST</taxRuleName>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <valueTaxable>183.00</valueTaxable>
    </TxnTaxes>
    <TxnMedia action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnMediaData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <amountLocal>183.00</amountLocal>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>0</detailNumber>
      <differenceLocal>0.00</differenceLocal>
      <expectedLocal>183.00</expectedLocal>
      <mediaInfoMediaNumber>1</mediaInfoMediaNumber>
      <mediaInfoMediaTypeMediaType>1</mediaInfoMediaTypeMediaType>
      <reference>170100</reference>
      <state>0</state>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tenderDateTime>2016-04-27 14:20:21.27</tenderDateTime>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <type>10</type>
    </TxnMedia>
    <TxnMedia action="3" class="uk.co.datafit.beanstore.server.TxnMediaData">
      <version>
        <database>3.332.15</database>
        <build>BS45.0.33.0</build>
      </version>
      <amountLocal>0.00</amountLocal>
      <companyCode>DJ01</companyCode>
      <detailNumber>1</detailNumber>
      <differenceLocal>0.00</differenceLocal>
      <expectedLocal>0.00</expectedLocal>
      <mediaInfoMediaNumber>1</mediaInfoMediaNumber>
      <mediaInfoMediaTypeMediaType>1</mediaInfoMediaTypeMediaType>
      <state>0</state>
      <storeCode>2116</storeCode>
      <tenderDateTime>2016-04-27 14:20:21.28</tenderDateTime>
      <tillNumber>1</tillNumber>
      <transactionNumber>78019</transactionNumber>
      <type>11</type>
    </TxnMedia>
  </transactionSale>'
        )
    )
    select xml2clob (txnheader.TxnXml)   from
    (
    select xml_det.TxnXml  
    FROM   origxml,  XMLTABLE('for $a in $c/transactionSale/TxnDetail
                      let $hdrdet := (for $x in $c/transactionSale/TxnHeader
                         return 
                      <hdr> 
                      <storeCode>{if (fn:exists ($x/sellingStore)) then $x/sellingStore/text() else $x/storeCode/text()}</storeCode>
                      <stime>{$x/startDateTime/text()}</stime>
                      </hdr>    )
                      let $strkey := substring(concat("0000",$hdrdet/storeCode),string-length(concat("0000",$hdrdet/storeCode)) -3,4)
                      let $dtekey := fn:replace($hdrdet/stime," ","-")
                      let $trnkey := substring(concat("000000",$a/transactionNumber),string-length(concat("000000",$a/transactionNumber)) -5,6)
                      let $tilkey := substring(concat("000",$a/tillNumber),string-length(concat("000",$a/tillNumber)) -2,3)
                      let $dtlkey := substring(concat("0000",$a/detailNumber),string-length(concat("0000",$a/detailNumber)) -3,4)
                      let $promo := (for $k in $c/transactionSale/InformationLine
                                              where $a/detailNumber = $k/txnDetailNr
                         and $k/valcConst = 430104
                         order by $k/sequenceNr
                       return <x>{xs:decimal($k/additionalInfo1) - xs:decimal($a/priceSold)}</x>)/text()
                      let $product := if(fn:exists($a/externalStockNumber))
                      then $a/externalStockNumber/text()
                      else db2-fn:sqlquery("select xmlcast((PRODUCT_ID) as xml) from rds.RDS_PRODUCT 
                       where DEPARTMENT_NUM = parameter(1) and TRACK_NUM = parameter(2)",
                       if ($a/sellingDepartmentCode <= 9999)  then $a/sellingDepartmentCode else 1,fn:substring-after($a/skuCode,"-")) 
                      let $store   := $a/storeCode
                      let $delivered :=  (for $m in $c/transactionSale/TxnDetail
                        where $m/sellingDepartmentCode = 601943
                        and not(fn:exists($m/itemVoid))
                        return  <y>Y</y>)/text()
                      let $saleamount := $a/valueLineAllDiscounts
                      let $detailno := $a/detailNumber
                      let $deptnum := $a/sellingDepartmentCode
                      let $deptyp :=  db2-fn:sqlquery("select xmlcast((department_typ) as xml) from rds.rds_department
                            where DEPARTMENT_NUM = parameter(1) ",if ($a/sellingDepartmentCode <= 9999)  then $a/sellingDepartmentCode else 1)
                      let $refund  := if ($a/lineRefund = 1) then -1 else 1
                      where not(fn:exists($a/itemVoid))
                      and ($a/transLineTypeTransLineType != 15 
                      and  $a/transLineTypeTransLineType != 21 
                      and  $a/transLineTypeTransLineType != 24 
                      and  $a/transLineTypeTransLineType != 57)
                      return <data>
                        {for $w in $c/transactionSale/TxnHeader
                         where $a/transactionNumber = $w/transactionNumber
                         return <x>
                         <void>{$w/voided/text()}</void>
                         <sourceSystem>{$w/sourceSystem/text()}</sourceSystem>
                         </x>}
                       <J2_GB_SALES>
                       <id>{concat($dtekey,$strkey,$tilkey,$trnkey,$dtlkey)}</id>
                       <processDate>{$trdate}</processDate>
                       <saleDate>{$a/saleDate/text()}</saleDate>
                       <transactionType>{if ($deptnum = 601943) then 3 else if ($refund = -1) then 2 else 1}</transactionType>
                       <storeCode>{$hdrdet/storeCode/text()}</storeCode>
                       {for $h in $c/transactionSale/TxnHeader
                        return 
                        <externalAccount>{$h/externalAccount/text()}</externalAccount>
                       }
                       {for $i in $c/transactionSale/TxnCustomer[1]
                       where $i/customerSubType = 0
                       and   $i/customerType = 1 
                        return 
                        <customer>
                        <customerCode>{$i/customerCode/text()}</customerCode>
                        <title>{$i/title/text()}</title>
                        <firstName> {if ($i/firstName/@encrypted =''true'') then db2-fn:sqlquery(" VALUES xmlcast(TRIM(  substr(RDS.PCMS_DECRYPTION( parameter(1) ),1,20)) as xml) ",$i/firstName/text() ) else $i/firstName/text() } </firstName>                                                            
                        <lastName>  {if ($i/lastName/@encrypted =''true'')  then db2-fn:sqlquery(" VALUES xmlcast(TRIM(  substr(RDS.PCMS_DECRYPTION( parameter(1) ),1,20)) as xml) ",$i/lastName/text() ) else $i/lastName/text() } </lastName>                                                                                    
                        <comment>{$i/comment/text()}</comment>
                        </customer>
                       }
                       {for $i in $c/transactionSale/TxnAddress[1]
                       where $i/addressSubTypeAddressSubType = 3
                       return
                       <telephoneNo>{$i/telephoneNumber/text()}</telephoneNo>
                       }
                       <giftId>{$a/extRefNo/text()}</giftId>
                       <deptNo>{$a/sellingDepartmentCode/text()}</deptNo>
                       <trackNo> {if ($a/sellingDepartmentCode <= 9999 )then fn:substring-after($a/skuCode,"-") else ""}</trackNo>
                       <classNo> {if ($a/sellingDepartmentCode <= 9999 )then fn:substring-after($a/level5Level5ID,"-") else 995}</classNo>
                       <barcode>{if(fn:exists($a/originalBarcode)) then $a/originalBarcode/text() else $a/pluNumber/text()}</barcode>
                       <saleQty>{if ($a/lineRefund = 1) then ($a/quantitySold/text() * -1) else ($a/quantitySold/text()) }</saleQty>

                      {for $e in $c/transactionSale/TxnDetailTaxes
                       where $detailno = $e/detailNumber
                        return 
                        <amounts>
                         <saleAmt>{($saleamount * $refund)}</saleAmt>
                        {for $f in $c/transactionSale/TxnDetailDiscount
                         where $detailno = $f/detailNumber
                         and $f/discountCodeDiscountTypeDiscountType !=8
                         and not(fn:exists($f/voided))
                         and ($f/discountCodeDiscountCode =1 and $f/discountCodeDiscountTypeDiscountType =4)
                         return 
                         <discounts>
                         <discountAmt>{0 - ($f/amount * $refund)}</discountAmt>
                         </discounts>
                         }
                         {for $g in $c/transactionSale/TxnDetailDiscount
                         let $reasoncode   := fn:string($g/reasonReasonCode/text())
                         let $reasontype   := $g/reasonReasonTypeReasonType/text()
                         where $detailno = $g/detailNumber
                         and not(fn:exists($g/voided))
                         and $g/discountCodeDiscountTypeDiscountType !=8
                         and ($g/discountCodeDiscountCode !=1 or $g/discountCodeDiscountTypeDiscountType !=4)
                         return 
                         <reductions>
                         <reductionAmt>{0 - ($g/amount * $refund)}</reductionAmt>
                         </reductions>
                         } 
                         <reductions>
                         <reductionAmt>{if (fn:exists($promo)) then (0 - $promo[1]) else if ($a/priceOverridden = 1 and $a/systemPrice != 0 )then 0 - ($a/systemPrice - $a/priceSold) else 0}</reductionAmt>
                         </reductions>
                        </amounts>
                      }
                       <assistantNo>{$a/operatorOperatorCode/text()}</assistantNo>
                       <productId>{$product}</productId>
                       <registerNo>{$a/tillNumber/text()}</registerNo>
                       <transactionNo>{substring(concat("000000",$a/transactionNumber),string-length(concat("000000",$a/transactionNumber)) -3,4)}</transactionNo>
                       <delivery>{if (fn:exists($delivered)) then "Y" else ""}</delivery>
                       </J2_GB_SALES>
                       </data>'
                            PASSING origxml.xdoc as  "c",
                                    utl.get_process_date_realtime () as "trdate"
                            COLUMNS
                      voided              CHAR(1)         path 'x/void/text()',
                      sourceSystem        varchar(10)     path 'x/sourceSystem/text()',
                      TxnXml              XML            PATH 'J2_GB_SALES/.') as xml_det 
                      where xml_det.voided is null
                      and xml_det.sourceSystem = 'GIFTRGSTRY'
                      )txnheader
with ur
```

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point. What kind of debugging have you tried? Maybe try printing out the **$i/firstName/@encrypted** and **$i/lastName/@encrypted** to make sure it is actually grabbing what you think it is.

Also trying changing it to false and see if it still runs no matter what.

Lastly according to what you sent it should be running on lastName, but not on firstName. So I assume the problem is that it runs on last name as well.

I find it odd that you chose to do ' 'true' ' instead of 'true' in your compare.
I'm not sure if that is the reason though. I know on the program I use SQL on that would cause issues.

Comment: I did try to change $i/firstName/@encrypted and $i/lastName/@encrypted to false, and removed the attributes as well, it just always executes the function call.   firstName initially has the attribute and I removed it for testing purpose.

Comment: Just to make sure....change the if statement to sayif 1 = 0. Or something that would never be true and make sure it doesn't call it.

Comment: I changed the if statement to 1 = 0, and it still executes the function call.. it seems like it will execute the statement below if regardless the if condition is true or not....